# Hyperlink simply changes the url, but the view remains unaltered

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs

What could cause a simple link

```
<a href="../../Test/Home.aspx">Home</a>
```

once clicked to only change the url visible at the browsers bar, but the rest of the page remain unaltered, and not follow the link?

I am only including Angular here because I am using it in my page, but the link behaves in a similar manner whether I use ng-href or not.

The one thing that I have done in Angular is

```
app.config(function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
});
```

But I dont think that it should effect a simple link in that way.

Comment: I believe this is directly related to your routing code , could you post your JS code as well

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) would be of use to you

Comment: @dreamweiver edited the question.

Comment: @Appelemac I never intended to get this behavior though, and I certainly havent used `onpostpone` or anything else.

Comment: can u try adding `<base href="/">` to your head and set `requireBase` to true because relative links won't work. *ref:https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location*  under `Reference Links`

Comment: The suggestion seems to have no effect.